# Android BindingAdapter with StringRes and ObservableField<String>

Tags: kotlin, data-binding

I'm facing an issue with complex databinding.

When I use a custom binding adapter with 1 arg, it works fine:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["myText"])
fun myBindingFun(
    view: View,
    myText: String?
) { ... }
```

```
myText="@{property.text}" <-- where text is an ObservableField<String>
```

But, as soon as I add a second args (a string res which needs an arg: "%s property"), compilation fails...

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["myText", "resourceId"])
fun myBindingFun(
    view: View,
    myText: String?,
    @StringRes resourceId: Int,
) { ... }
```

```
Cannot find a setter for ... that accepts parameter type 'androidx.databinding.ObservableField<java.lang.String>'

If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

When I add the second arg, I simply add resourceId property to my XML, that way:

```
myText="@{property.text}"
resourceId="@{@{string/my_string}}"
```

I've also try with

```
myText="@{property.text}"
resourceId="@string/my_string"
```

Have you ever face this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have sth like this in your xml layout file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="property"
            type="..." />
    <data>

        <View
            android:layout_width="..."
            android:layout_height="..."
            myText="@{property.text}"
            resourceId="..."/>

</layout>
```

If you want to pass the resourceId using BindingAdapter, you will need a bit of workaround. Update your `xml` file to:

```
    <data>

        <variable
            name="property"
            type="..." />

        <variable
            name="myStringResId"
            type="..." />
    <data>
        <View
            android:layout_width="..."
            android:layout_height="..."
            myText="@{property.text}"
            resourceId="@{myStringResId}"/>

</layout>
```

Then, in the place where you inflate your binding view, do:

```
binding.myStringResId = R.string.my_string
```

There's no direct way to pass the (int) resourceId to the xml as far as I know.

Now the following reading is optional. Suppose your `my_string` has this value:

```
<string name="my_string">I am awesome</string>
```

In the case of

```
resourceId="@{@{string/my_string}}"
```

you are actually passing the value itself (`I am awesome` in our case) - which is of type `String` - as the BindingAdapter's `resourceId` parameter, which expects `Int`, hence the error. If you change your BindingAdapter's second parameter to accept `String` instead of `Int`, it will work just fine.

Lastly, `resourceId="@string/my_string"` is not a valid annotation. I understand it looks logical, unfortunately with this your code will not compile.